# Cannot import Scapy ssl_tls library

Tags: python, scapy

I am using newest Kali and importing scapy ssl_tls package like this:

```
from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *
```

But I get an error: `WARNING: can't import layer ssl_tls: No module named ssl_tls`

or

`ImportError: No module named ssl_tls`.

Also, to [verify installation](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls#verify-installation), I go into Scapy prompt and type `TLS` or `SSL` I get:

```
>>> TLS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TLS' is not defined
```

So it makes me believe that I didn't install it correctly. However I tried all 3 installation methods from [official page](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls) and all worked without any errors.

I also have SSL installed: `apt-get install libssl-dev`

**My system:**
Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Python2.7

Scapy version 2.2.1. Also tried 2.3.1.

scapy-ssl_tls version - current from https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls

```
root@kali:~/Downloads# pip freeze | grep scapy
Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
scapy==2.2.0-dev
scapy-ssl-tls==1.2.1
```

**NOTE**: I have same exact python code running good on different Kali machine, on the same Python, Scapy and scapy-ssl_tls versions.

Comment: Please, specify your platform (win/linux/mac), python (2.x or 3.x?) and scapy versions.

Comment: Provided requested info in the end of original question.

Comment: `pip install scapy-ssl_tls` worked fine on my kali2 box. would you mind providing some more detailed information by opening an issue in the github issue tracker (kali image, version, scapy locations)?

Comment: Based on the official page you cannot import it with before 2.4.0 versions.  warning requires scapy==2.4.0. support with scapy before v2.4 is broken due to major changes in scapy.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed ssl_tls using pip. Using this installation method in my case config.py was not updated with added layer, which means that running scapy does not import ssl_tls automatically thus it is not possible to do `from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *`. Your case sounds similar.

There are 2 options:

- Update scapy's config.py (location depends on the way you installed scapy) by adding ssl_tls module. See https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls#option-3-manual-installation for example
- Import module using `from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import *` after importing scapy (or running scapy directly)

Answer (score 1):

[github/scapy-ssl_tls PR #55](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/pull/55) fixes an issue where setup.py would not find all scapy installation dirs in case you have multiple locations for site-packages. Also see the updated installation [instructions](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls) and troubleshooting. The fix is in master and will be in scapy-ssl_tls > 1.2.2. Please give it a try and raise a bug on github if this does not fix the issue for you. thanks

Comment: I used pip to do the install. I wasn't able to import from scapy.layers.ssl_tls into python scripts. I tried the second method in the installation instructions, it didn't help either.

Comment: Would you be so kind and file a bug with all relevant information (distri, paths, steps-2-reproduce) in the github repo? https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/issues

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your python version is > 2.7.6 and then run 'pip install scapy-ssl_tls'